# Does jQuery need a server like Apache to run?

Tags: javascript

Am trying to install jQuery. I downloaded it from the official page and placed it in my workspace folder and referenced it in the html file. I can't however get the results to show its configured. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a Javascript Library.

## How to check if jQuery is imported :

- Open your HTML page on browser.
- Open Developement tools (Console) , Press`F12` .
- Run this JS code : `jQuery`

[image]

Comment: I want to import it in an html file using code . For example in Notepad++